# Reindex dataframe reverse multiindex levels

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas dataframe with a Multindex of "group" and "date" that I want to convert into one with the indices reversed, ie. "date" then "group". I've tried reindexing but this sets all values to NaN.

I tried this:

```
by_date = MultiIndex.from_product([index.levels[1], index.levels[0]])
df.reindex(index=by_date)


                  Nuts  Bolts  Screws
group date                           
1010  2020-03-13   1.0   44.0     1.0
      2020-02-19   2.0   44.0     0.0
3510  2020-03-13   1.0   26.0     1.0
5000  2020-02-28   1.0    3.0     0.0
3510  2020-03-02   2.0   26.0     0.0
```

And I would like this format

```
                 Nuts  Bolts  Screws
date        group                            
2020-03-13  1010    1.0   44.0     1.0
```

Is this possible reindexing? Or am I better unstacking and stacking?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
df1 = df.swaplevel(0,1)

#oldier pandas version
#df.index = df.index.swaplevel(0,1)
print (df1)
                  Nuts  Bolts  Screws
date       group                     
2020-03-13 1010    1.0   44.0     1.0
2020-02-19 1010    2.0   44.0     0.0
2020-03-13 3510    1.0   26.0     1.0
2020-02-28 5000    1.0    3.0     0.0
2020-03-02 3510    2.0   26.0     0.0
```

Comment: I thought they'd be a **simple and obvious** way to do this. Thanks very much!